# What makes sea food have similar smell?

Tags: fish, smell

I never ate fish, I always disliked the smell and had a little bit of trauma with my father forcing me to eat it while I was a kid. I had two experiences:

- Some years ago, I tried sushi. It doesn't have a strong smell of fish and I found it edible. But there is a very faint smell of fish.
- Some days ago, I bought some chips made of Nori algae. They were vegan chips and yet, I felt the same soft smell of fish.

I conjectured that perhaps, part of this smell is common to all things in the sea. Lately, I decided to do indoor farming and when studying about fertilizers, I heard someone saying that "certain fertilizers with phosphorus have a smell of fish and that the sea is rich in phosphorus" so, this seems to be my first guess. I understand that my question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 4):

The [American Society for Nutrition](https://nutrition.org/is-fish-smelly/) explains it thus:

> The answer has to do with some interesting physiology unique to sea
> creatures.Water in the open ocean is about 3% salt by weight, but the
> optimal levels of dissolved minerals inside an animal cell is less
> than 1%.In order to maintain fluid balance, ocean creatures must fill
> their cells with amino acids and amines to counter the saltiness of
> seawater. Ocean fish tend to rely on trimethylamine oxide (TMAO) for
> this purpose.

- Now this compound does not in itself have a particularly pungent odour, however:

> The problem is that when fish are killed, bacteria and fish enzymes
> convert TMAO into trimethylamine (TMA), which gives off the
> characteristic “fishy” odor.This smell can be reduced in two ways.TMA
> on the surface of the fish can be rinsed off with tap water.Treating
> the fish with acidic ingredients such as lemon, vinegar, or tomato can
> also cause TMA to bind to water and become less volatile.Thus the odor
> compounds do not reach the nose.

This [trimethylamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimethylamine) is something that is produced in small quantities by our own gut microbes, and usually is no trouble when kept under control - some however are unfortunatley prone to "[Fish Odour Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimethylaminuria)".

- I am not able to find any definitive evidence for the reason that **nori** smells of fish, however, an uncorroborated suggestion behind the scenes on a Wikipedia [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Nori) page states this:

> Please. **Fish smells of algae, not the other way around!** For the same
> reason DHAs are not "fish oils", but "algae oils".--Rfsmit

<sub>*Bolding Mine*</sub>

- As they are so ubiquitous in nature it would seem likely that the bacteria that convert the TMAO into TMA and make the smell would be present on the **algae** as well as in the fish and in our own guts.

## Conclusion.

- I'd claim that the bacteria and what it eats and it's waste products are to blame for the similar smell: it would seem to be the case that [Japanese Nori](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3892503/) (There mis-classified as genus [Porphyra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyropia)) contains amino acids and nutrients not inconsistent with the culprit bacteria growing on it (As it also like fish flesh). As I say I can not offer anything definitive.